# Cannot find symbol class Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am new in android development and coding java and xml.

but I was following this tutorial:

http://www.steventrigg.com/activities-and-the-action-bar-create-an-alarm-clock-in-android-tutorial-part-1/#comment-296

then I had this error when using Intent. The word "Intent" under switch became red and there is an error "cannot find symbol class Intent"

Can someone explain to me what is going on and how to solve this?

This is the last part of my code under AlarmListActivity.java

```
@Override

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

   int id = item.getItemId();
   if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
       return true;
   }

   switch (item.getItemId()) {
       case R.id.action_add_new_alarm: {
           Intent intent = new Intent(this,
                   AlarmDetailsActivity.class);

            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: The word Intent is not red here, but its red in my java. what is wrong? I also have the following error message

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

What is this?

Comment: That error message isn't an error. It's just a notification that you can't compile your class with the existing errors.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Look at your AlarmListActivity again and check the import statements at the top and make sure it includes the line:

```
import android.content.Intent;
```

If you intend to use any pre-existing classes that aren't part of the `java.lang` package, you generally have to import those classes. An Android `Intent`, for example, is a pre-built class, written by the Android development team, that allows for notification of other apps/activities. If you want to use `Intent`, you'd then have to import the package containing Intent.

When you write `new Intent()`, the compiler sees that you're requesting the construction of a new object, but because that object is not found in the `java.lang` package, it needs to know where to look for a blueprint to build that object. The import statement is the location of that blueprint.

I took a look at the tutorial and in the manner of experienced programmers, the author seems to have glossed over a few basic, but nonetheless, important things, such as the import statements that make his sample code work.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think it's working. but now the word "Intent" and "AlarmDetailsActivity" becomes black. Are they supposed to be blue? or it doesn't matter?

Can you give me a brief explanation about import? HOw often do I need to import something? and how do I know if I need to import something and what to write?

The error I mentioned also dissapeared, so I think its good.

Comment: Take a look at this [tutorial](http://howtoprogramwithjava.com/java-imports/) for more information on imports. I didn't look at it too closely, but at first blush, it seems to cover all the bases. If this answer helped you, please click the checkmark next to it so people seeing this question in the future will know what worked. If you have additional questions, feel free to post them separately.

Answer (score 4):

I had a same problem which I just resolved, by understanding how Android Studio indexes files, As you know Building an Android App is quite complicated process. So Android studio has some internal references which it keeps getting updated on change of every file that you have created.

I arrived at this post while searching for the solution,

This is how I got this problem

I usually wont create an activity under the main project package, I create sub packages to organize files as per the design pattern that I use, for eg If my APP name is com.example.testingaravind then inside that I usually create packages such as activites, services, models, managers etc ... So today I just created an activity first and then moved that activity into activites package via Android Studio, I started facing the same issue what you have described, Below was my source code

```
    public class BootstrapActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

        private static final String TAG = "BootstrapActivity";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_bootstrap);
        }

        public void startServiceOnClickHandler(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(BootstrapActivity.this , AnalyzerService.class);
            startService(intent);
        }
}
```

In the method startServiceOnClickHandler it was showing an error saying, 
"Cannot resolve constructor Intent" I searched a lot in google and found that

When I move a file from one package to other package, my manifest file wont get updated, in the manifest we mention the activity name and its package path in my case it should be

```
   android:name=".activities.BootstrapActivity"
```

But it was

```
   android:name=".BootstrapActivity"
```

Because of this, Android studio was unaware that a class called BootstrapActivity exists inside the activities folder,

This seems to be a bug in the way how android studio works. Android Studio has to update manifestfile when I move the activity class file from one package to another package.

I am posting this to help others who might arrive at this post with the similar usecase.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is very helpful for me to further understand android development. That being said, my problem was actually a simple of not importing the intent. i faced this problem when I was just starting my learning of android development. But thank you for the answer. It is very educational and will be useful in the future.

Answer (score 1):

```
     Check name in manifest file in activity tag specify correct package for example your 
              <activity
                android:name="Your-Package.MainActivity"
                android:exported="true" />
 In second case If you are using kotlin class inside java class, after configuring kotlin in project can solve the project...
```